# How can I draw a grid of colored rectangles in QT c++?

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, qt5, heatmap

I am trying to implement something similar to heatmaps. the only thing different from conventional heatmaps is that each rectangle has a color and a different width than the ones next to it.
all rectangles on the same level has the same height.
I tried to draw consecutive rectangles by setting the ending position of the first rectangle to be the starting position of the second, and so on.
The problem is that they overlap heavily and each one doesn't start after the one before it ends.

Can I specify the exact pixel position where I want a rectangle to start and end in QT?

here is my code trying to do so:

```
 int lastX = 0;
 int lastY = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < x-1; i++){
        int j=0;
        for(j = 0; j < y-1; j++){
            //set brush opacity
            painter.setOpacity(avgs[i][j]- floor(avgs[i][j]));

            int color = avgs[i][j];
            if(color <= 1){
                painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::red));
            }
            else if(color <= 2){
                painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::green));
            }
            else if(color <= 3){
                painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::blue));
            }
            else {
                painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::yellow));
            }
            //widths and heights are arrays that carry the width and height for each rectangle 
            int endX = lastX + widths[i];
            int endY = lastY + heights[j];
            painter.drawRect(lastX, endX, lastY, endY);
            lastX = endX;

            }
            lastY = lastY + heights[i];
            lastX = 0;
    }
```

and this is the result I get:
[image]

but what I need is something like this:
[image]

any idea on how I can achieve this in QT?

Comment: Take a look at QGraphicsView

Comment: Note that the third and fourth argument of [`drawRect`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawRect-1) are width and height, not the coordinate of the "end" position.